# Solution of a nonlinear system of two equations

Tags: matrices, nonlinear-optimization

Given the matrix $A_{M,N}$ with $N\gt M$, the vector $y$, I have to find the vectors $x$ and $u$, satisfying the following equations:
$$D(x)x=A^Tu$$
$$y=Ax$$
where: $$D(x) = \left| \begin{array}{ccc}
\exp(-x_1^2/2\sigma^2) & 0 & ... \\
0 & \exp(-x_2^2/2\sigma^2)& ... \\
... & ... & ...\\0 &0&\exp(-x_M^2/2\sigma^2) \end{array} \right| $$ The vector $x$ is:
$$x=\left( \begin{array}{ccc}
x_1 \\
... \\
x_M \end{array} \right)$$ in which $x_1,x_2,...x_M$ are the unknown variables.
The vector $u$ is:
$$u=\left( \begin{array}{ccc}
u_1 \\
... \\
u_N \end{array} \right)$$
Is there some way to solve it? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Why do you *have* to do this?

Comment: @FernandoMuro: It's a problem arising in the field of signal processing. I need to solve it before to proceed with other calculation.

Comment: So $A$ is actually $N \times M$?  And did you really want $N > M$, or the reverse?

Comment: @RobertIsrael: I want $M\gt N$